# Select all text objects on a Fabric.js canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas, fabricjs

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas();

// select all objects
function selectAllCanvasObjects(){
    var objs = canvas.getObjects().map(function(o) {
        return o.set('active', true);
    });

    var group = new fabric.Group(objs, {
        originX: 'center', 
        originY: 'center'
    });

    canvas._activeObject = null;

    canvas.setActiveGroup(group.setCoords()).renderAll();
}
```

I have a canvas and I need to select all text objects and skip others. This is the code to select all objects, how can I make it only select all text objects and skip others?

Answer (score 2):

The following example only selects items with the `type` of `'text'`.

In summary:

- The Fabric JS `get` method allows us to inspect the `type` of the current item that we're iterating over
- If the `type` is equal to `'text'` then we return the item
- N.B. We now use `filter` instead of `map`, as we now only want to return items that match the type of `'text'`, instead of every item

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

// Add some example shapes
var circle = new fabric.Circle({
  radius: 20, fill: 'green', left: 100, top: 100
});
var triangle = new fabric.Triangle({
  width: 20, height: 30, fill: 'blue', left: 50, top: 50
});

canvas.add(circle, triangle);

// Add some example text
var text1 = new fabric.Text('hello world', { left: 100, top: 100 });

var text2 = new fabric.Text('test', { left: 0, top: 0 });

canvas.add(text1, text2);

// Select all objects
function selectAllCanvasObjects(){
    var objs = canvas.getObjects().filter(function(o) {
        if (o.get('type') === 'text') {
            return o.set('active', true);
        }
    });

    var group = new fabric.Group(objs, {
        originX: 'center', 
        originY: 'center'
    });

    canvas._activeObject = null;

    canvas.setActiveGroup(group.setCoords()).renderAll();
}

selectAllCanvasObjects();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.8/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Comment: Hello i am the same person , i have a i use the simple you make it work just fine but i have 1 problem , the function select all i want to set into a button , when i click multiple time the group position will jump , how do i make sure the group stay in position.?

Comment: try click the button few time.

Comment: @user3233074 Perhaps worthwhile posting this as a new question. I'll take a look, but I'm not very familiar with the Fabric JS API, so probably good to see if anyone else can help too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to select all text object.

```
var object_length   = parseInt(canvas.getObjects().length) - 1;
for(var i = 0; i <= object_length; i++)
{
    canvas.setActiveObject(canvas.item(i));

    var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
    var object_type = obj.type;

    if(object_type == "text")
    {
        //Write your code here
        canvas.renderAll();
    }
}
canvas.deactivateAllWithDispatch();
canvas.renderAll();
```

After completion of execution deselect all objects so it will not show you last selected object as selected.